# How to re-map with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an object with following data for instance *(Elasticsearch result)*

```
{createdat: {raw: 2022-01-26T16:49:24.000Z}, images: {raw: []}}
```

In Flutter I would like to (re)map this object to look like

```
{createdat: 2022-01-26T16:49:24.000Z, images: []}
```

So the challenge is to get the value of each "raw" and get it one level up.

Is there an easy method to solve that task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
void main() {
  final originalMap = {
    'createdat': {'raw': '2022-01-26T16:49:24.000Z'},
    'images': {'raw': []}
  };
  final convertedMap = originalMap.map((key, value) => 
    MapEntry(key, value['raw']));
  print(convertedMap);
}
```

Comment: since `value['raw']`  might be null, you'll want to have  some way to keep it out of the result if it's not present.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz If `value['raw']` is null, the converted result will contain null for the corresponding key, which might be actually the desired behaviour.